# Add 1 to object property if it exists, create and set it to 1 if it doesn't (javascript)

Tags: javascript, object

So I have the following code and it is doing what I want it to but I was just wondering if there was a better way of doing this. It just feels clunky

```
object.hasOwnProperty(property) ? object[property]++ : object[property] = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this :

```
obj.prop = obj.prop + 1 || 1
```

This works just like your original code but with an OR statement, it will take the first option that is true. Since the object might not have the property, it'll return 'NaN' and then proceed to set the property to 1 since that is the other side of the OR statement.

To avoid this case :

```
obj.prop = (obj.prop && obj.prop + 1) || 1
```

Comment: Another take `obj.prop = (obj.prop || 0) + 1`